# AWS Cognito UserPool RecoveryOptions - CloudFormation vs Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito

Are the recovery options available [via CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-recoveryoption.html) really limited compared to those in the console (seem image below) or am I missing something?

CloudFormation:
[image]

Console:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i think it has it all. RecoveryMechanisms is List of options or may be skipped. Options has priority setting too.

Following your screenshot:

[image]

for #1 - provide 2 mechanisms (phone & email), with priority for email

for #2 - provide 2 mechanism (phone & email), with priority for phone

for #3 - email only

for #4 - phone only

for # 5 - Skip `AccountRecoverySetting` from UserPool and you have legacy (Not Recommended) option. [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cognito-userpool.html#cfn-cognito-userpool-accountrecoverysetting)

for # 6 - Then you can define admin only, which is last one.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-accountrecoverysetting.html

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-cognito-userpool-recoveryoption.html

Comment: Usually aws console is lacking of options. You can do everything with aws cli & aws sdk, then with cloudformation and only then with console. That's the general rule. By the way, if you can't do something with cloudformation, you can have custom resource and run lambda with cloudformation to rone sdk call.